# Visibility change behavior is different after Oreo

Tags: android, kotlin, android-animation

I've recently found that depending on your android sdk, when changing visibility of a view, it behaves differently.

Before Oreo, when setting from `VISIBLE` to `GONE`, the view first fade from 1 to 0 in terms of alpha, then the place that the view used collapse.

For Oreo and later (I suppose I haven't tested on Android Q), when setting from `VISIBLE` to `GONE`, the view collapse while fading, doing clipping with other views, since the alpha hasn't been set to zero yet.

I haven't found anything on this particular case, only that I had to do myself back the animation on some post by customizing my views.

I will answer myself below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I created my custom view and after lots of debugging, I found that I needed to override the `setAlpha` method :

```
class CustomViewAnimation(context: Context, attributeSet: AttributeSet) : ConstraintLayout(context, attributeSet) {

    private fun callToSuper(alpha: Float) {
        super.setAlpha(alpha)
    }

    override fun setAlpha(alpha: Float) {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
            super.setAlpha(alpha)
        else {
            if (this.visibility == View.GONE)
                super.setAlpha(0f)
            else if (this.visibility == View.VISIBLE && alpha != 1f)
                super.setAlpha(0f)
            else if (this.visibility == View.VISIBLE && alpha == 1f)
                this.animate()
                    .alpha(1f)
                    .setListener(object : Animator.AnimatorListener {
                        override fun onAnimationRepeat(animation: Animator?) {}

                        override fun onAnimationEnd(animation: Animator?) {
                            callToSuper(1f)
                        }

                        override fun onAnimationCancel(animation: Animator?) {}

                        override fun onAnimationStart(animation: Animator?) {}
                    })
        }
    }
}
```

You also have to do the other part of the animation in your code where you want to change the visibility :

```
if (view.visibility == View.VISIBLE) {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        view.animate()
            .alpha(0.0f)
            .setListener(object : Animator.AnimatorListener {
                override fun onAnimationRepeat(animation: Animator?) {}

                    override fun onAnimationEnd(animation: Animator?) {
                        view.alpha = 0.0f
                        view.visibility = View.GONE
                    }

                        override fun onAnimationCancel(animation: Animator?) {}

                        override fun onAnimationStart(animation: Animator?) {}
                })
        } else
            view.visibility = View.GONE
    } else
        view.visibility = View.VISIBLE
```

This may not be the best way due to the lots of conditions, but again, I haven't found anything else and this works very well.